# Facebook Javascript SDK response properties

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a list with all the properties I can ask using response after user was authenticated?  like response.name, response.last_name and other?  I would like to see a full list..

Answer (score 4):

Include the line:

```
console.log(response);
```

in your Javascript. Then load up Firebug in your favourite modern browser and go to the console tab. You should be able to view the response as an object.

Answer (score -2):

A full response object for you case should look like this:

```
{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        access_token: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}
```